# In emacs, how do I get ${VARIABLE} within a string to be highlighted?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

Using emacs in a terminal, when programming in BASH, `${VARIABLE}` gets highlighted:

```
#!/bin/sh
.
.
.
ls ${VARIABLE}
.
.
.
```

But `"${VARIABLE}"` does not, as in:

```
#!/bin/sh
.
.
.
ls "${VARIABLE}"
.
.
.
```

In the above, `${VARIABLE}` is highlighted only as a string; that is, the variable inside the string is not highlighted differently.

What do I need to put into my .emacs file to make sure it highlights properly?

Comment: Works for me. What is your emacs version? Are you in Shell-script[sh] -mode or Shell-script[bash]?

Comment: FYI -- it's conventional for non-environment variables to be lower-case to prevent them from conflicting with shell-builtin variables (which are all-uppercase) or environment variables (which are all-upper-case by convention).

Comment: When you "M-x eval-expression<ret> (sh-set-shell "bash" nil nil)<ret>", do you have the same results?

Comment: @ChenLevy You must have a different version than me (built from bzr less than a week ago) since in the known bugs section of `sh-script.el` it says: Variables in " strings aren't fontified because there's no way of syntactically distinguishing those from ' strings.  Maybe you are thinking of `$()`?